# Angular 4 - Remove multiple rows from table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am already capable of removing a single row from a table using splice.
What I want now is to remove multiple rows

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let member of members; let i = index;">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="selChk(member.id, i)"  
      [checked]="false">
    </td>
</tr>
```

so every loop every row will be labeled as 0,1,2,3,4 ...

**component**

*below is the list of ids from checkbox I checked.*

when I checked, for example, the first and second row. it will get the row 0,1. then I will click the remove multiple buttons to splice the record using rows

```
selChk(val:number, ind:number) {

  var i =  this.id.indexOf(val);
   if(i === -1){
     this.id.push(val);
     this.ind.push(index);
   }else{
     this.id.splice(index,1);
   }

}
```

codes below will trigger when I click the remove multiple buttons. returns the correct row to be deleted. **but I don't know how to splice multiple.**

```
 removeSel() {
   console.log(this.ind);
  }
```

Comment: What is the name of total data where you are looping build the table?

Comment: `function removeMany(array, indexes = []) {
  return array.filter((_, idx) => indexes.indexOf(idx) === -1)
}`  try this ? where array is your original array and indexes is your `this.ind`

Comment: I revised my post

Comment: @edizonv did you tried above code ?

Comment: yes I tried it.  removeSel() {
   
   
     this.members.filter((_, idx) => this.ind.indexOf(idx) === -1);
   
  
  } but nothing happens

Comment: @edizonv check out this fiddle with sample array http://jsfiddle.net/n2gzfnf3/

Comment: @Rahul, ahhm it should return only 2. because YOU remove the 1 3 4

Comment: @rahul,, yes per index. I return the correct index, but I cant remove multiple rows.

Comment: @edizonv i removed as per index....so 1st 3rd and 4th index will get removed  !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157542/discussion-between-rahul-and-edizonv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below function in your component code :

```
 removeSel() {
  this.members = this.members.filter((_, idx) =>this.ind.indexOf(idx) === -1)
 }
```

call this removeSel function on click of your remove multiple button : 
`(click) = "removeSel()"`

Ref :
[MDN Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)